# find $p$, $k$ that probablity for two players is equal

Tags: probability

A, and B play the following game:
They throw coin (A and B have own coins) until first tail (probablity $p$).
Let A did need $a$ throws, B did need $b$ throws.
Player A win if $a=b$, player B win if $|a-b|=k$.
Find $p,k$ such that probablity that A and B have the same chance to win.

Ok, so I will try. Now, I ask for clues to solution. I understood my errors.

$X$ - probablity that both players have the same chance to win.

So,
$Pr(x)=Pr(X|a=b)Pr(a=b) + Pr(X|a>b)Pr(a>b)+Pr(X|a<b)Pr(a<b) $
When $a=b$ player A win with prob $1$ so. $Pr(X|a=b)=0$
What about $Pr(X|a>b)$ ? $Then\ b = a + c$ and probablity that A win is $p^2q^{a-1}q^{a+c-1}=p^2q^{2a-2+c}$
What is probablity that B win ? It is $Pr(c=k)=1/c $
$Pr(X|a>b) = p^2q^{2a-2+c} \cdot 1/c $

$Pr(a>b)$     Hmm, How to compute it ? Have I properly solved it So far ?

Answer (score 1):

The probability you found for B to win is not quite right. For suppose for example that $k=3$. Then B wins if $a=1$ and $b=4$. Apart from an algebra error, you computed the probability of that correctly.

But your formula has two terms. Note that it is not possible to have $a=1$ and $b=-2$. So for this case your formula, even with the algebra corrected, does not give the right answer.

To correct the algebra error, note that the probability that A gets her head at $a$ and B gets her head at $b$ should be $p^2q^{a-1}q^{b-1}$. If $b=a+k$ that is $p^2 q^{2a+k-2}$.

But correcting the algebra will not fix the problem that arises when (for example) $a=1$ and $k=3$.

**Added:** To bypass the problem, for fixed $a$, calculate the probability A gets $a$ and B gets $a+k$.  Sum over all $a$ (geometric series). Then **double** the result.

Comment: I don't understand. So what is Ok ? What is wrong. Tell more exactly please

Comment: Two things are wrong. The second one is minor, easily corrected, and is pointed out in the sentence I recently added. Your probability that $a$ and $b$ differ by $k$ in absolute value is wrong for some $a,k$. It is OK for $a=17$, $k=3$. But it is not OK for $a=1$, $k=3$.

Comment: Ok, first wrong: $Pr(A\ won) = Pr(a=b) = p^2q^{2a-2} = p^2q^{2b-2} $ Ok ?

Comment: When it comes to second erorr. $Pr(b)=Pr(b=a+k\ or\ a=b+k)= p^2q^{a+k-1 + a - 1} + p^2q^{b - 1 + b+ k -1} $ ok?

Comment: That's the first fix, minor. Need a related fix for the probability that $A=a$ and $B=b$. That's just algebra. No big deal. The messier stuff is that for some $a,k$ we do not have two terms in the probability.

Comment: Further, the prob of A winning will need a summation across all possible values of a. Similarly for B winning. Then you equate the sums.

Comment: Ok, tell me more please

Comment: Yes, but the *summands* are not always the ones you gave.

Comment: I'm giving up, help me :)

Comment: I have fairly fully pointed out errors in your probability calculation, which is what you asked for. I assume you are now asking for a solution of the original problem. If that is the question you want to ask, perhaps it should be a new one, with some indication of what you know. As an alternative, you could edit your question to indicate that you want a solution of the original problem. The downside is that as an "old" question it may get less attention.

Comment: I edited my first posts

Comment: In order to help, I had added a couple of lines. Do it that way. So sum $p^2q^{2a+k-2}$ from $a=1$ to $\infty$, double, and set equal to the probability of equality, which is the sum from $a=1$ to $\infty$ of $p^2q^{2a-2}$. The equation turns out to be quite handlable, the ugly stuff cancels.